# Download URL of Microsoft patches

Tags: com, wuapi

I'm making my own project where I will search for Microsoft updates but will not download/install using `WUA API`. I will use `WUA API` only for detection and to get the properties of the individual patches.

To make the above scenario work, through `ISearchResult` I can get the update interface. From that there is one property `DownloadContent` which will give me the `IUpdateDownloadContentCollection` interface through which I will get `IUpdateDownloadContent` interface and finally I can get download URL of the specified patch.

Initially the `DownloadUrl` property of `IUpdateDownloadContent` was not able to give any url. Later then I found out that `downloadUrl` was only available for patches of `type ='Driver'`, and not for "Software type".

I searched through internet but no luck :(.

The reason I don't want to use COM API for downloading and installing is because I have seen whenever we use `WUA API` to download or install , the process "trustedinstaller.exe" starts running and takes most of the system resources and slowing it down.

Can someone please tell me why I'm not able to receive `DownloadUrl` for patches/updates of type = 'Software'.

Answer (score 2):

After doing so much research I finally got the answer.
To get the  `DownloadUrl` of `Type = Software` we have to use `BundledUpdates` property of `Iupdate` interface which will point out to the `IupdateClassification`which in turn will gives us `Iupdate` interface from here we can get the `DownloadUrl` from `DownloadContent`

Comment: It is not that simple, because for each update, `BundledUpdates`  is a collection with possible several bundled updates and for each bundle in the `BundledUpdates`,  `DownloadContent` is again a collection with several  files with a different `DownloadUrl`. So you need to add the logic to identify  what bundle and download you need.

Comment: @ajit, @antonio Collection name is `DownloadContents`, not `DownloadContent`

Answer (score -1):

This PSEUDO-CODE shows how to get all URL-s of the searched updates.

```
SearchResult = UpdateSearcher.Search("Type='Software'")

FOR EACH (SearchResult.Updates AS Update) {
  FOR EACH (Update.BundledUpdates AS BundledUpdate) {
    FOR EACH (BundledUpdate.DownloadContents AS DownloadContent) {
      
      DISPLAY DownloadContent.DownloadUrl

    }
  }
}
```